# two dlmenu on same page do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using dlmenu, it works properly.

But I have sticked top line of my website. I use dlmenu on mobile, when screen size less then 992px. When I scroll I see sticked menu, but when I click to it it doesn't work. But if I click to real menu (not sticked) it works fine.

```
if($(window).width() < 992){
    $('#dl-menu').addClass('dl-menuwrapper');
    $('#dl-menu').removeClass('main-mnu');
    $('.headhesive--stick > #dl-menu').dlmenu();
    $('header .top-line #dl-menu').dlmenu();
};
```

I tried also this

```
$('.headhesive #dl-menu .dl-trigger').click(function(){
$('.dl-menu').addClass("dl-menuopen");
```

});

But sticked menu still doesn't work.
Please, help.

The link to the webstite:
http://tecrailway.com

Answer (score 0):

it has 2 `#dl-menu` but only one has event listener, try using `setTimeout` to add listener to second `#dl-menu`.

do you recreating `#dl-menu`? it not valid html because `id` can be only one so I change listener to class `.dl-menuwrapper`

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.dl-menuwrapper').dlmenu();
}, 999);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16796093)

Comment: I know what I'm doing, try before coment.

Comment: Thank's, but in the very beginning I tried exactly $('#dl-menu').dlmenu(); and it worked only with original menu, but not with stick.

Comment: not work because you have 2 `#dl-menu` and only one have event listener so you have to call it twice

Comment: Could you, please, show what I should insert to my js file. Thank you!